# Torrents don't download in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, bittorrent, transmission

I've been using Linux (Kubuntu) for about two months. I liked the torrent client that came with it (ktorrent), but recently I've noticed that ktorrent doesn't download again even if the torrent has over a thousand seeders, so I tried switching to qbitorrent. That doesn't download either!

My internet speed is 100Mbps so I guess that's not the issue. I've tried uninstalling and installing again but it doesn't help.

What should I do? Is there a log file that might help diagnose the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ok First thing to do here is to check if your firewall is blocking ktorrent from downloading torrents but i dont think Kubuntu comes with a firewall settings managers so install firehol instead by running sudo apt-get install firehol in the terminal .

Also go the preferences in Ktorrent and change your default port to something else (just change the didgits there to something else but with the same amount of digits) . You could also try to enable DHT checkbox in 'BitTorrent' section of the configuration menu.

Comment: please how do i check my firewall settings with firehol...thought i can't remember using any firewall.i've also tried changing the digits and enabling dht but it's not working

Comment: to learn how to configre firehol visit http://firehol.org/documentation/

Comment: also try changing your port to 57558

Answer (score 0):

Transmission is the best torrent client for Linux/Ubuntu I have ever tried. You can install Transmission using this code in a terminal window:

```
   sudo apt-get install transmission transmission-gtk
```

After you're done with installing the app, you should open Transmission and change a few settings in there from the Preferences menu:

- In the Torrents tab mark **Stop Seeding at ratio** and choose value 1.00
- In the Speed tab, mark both **Limit upload speed** and **Limit download speed** and change the values in there to at least 1500kib/s for Upload and at least 5000kib/s for Download
- While still in the Speed tab, go to temporary speed limits and choose similar values for both upload and download speed. Eg. 1600 kib/s Upload and 6000 kib/s Download
- In the Privacy tab, mark **Use Local Peer Discovery**
- In the Network tab, first make sure to test your port for incoming connections by pressing the **Test Port** button, and if all is ok, you should go to **Limits** under the same tab for Network and increase value for **Peers** to 1024 in both fields

And this should be all. Close Transmission, and next time you open it, you should see increased performance for both downloading and uploading your favorite torrents.

If you still experience issues while downloading torrent files, try to change your Download folder for torrents, default is ~/home/user/Downloads, to another folder present in your ~/home/user/ directory, for instance make a new folder and name it **Torrents** or whatever.

IF, by any chance, you played recently with your "Accounts and Users" settings, in Kubuntu general settings, you should make sure that your user account has full administrative privilegies and it is not restricted in any way for network access.